# fatal: bad object xxx

Tags: git

I tried reverting to a previous git commit with:

```
git revert xxx
```

I'm now receiving this error as a response:

```
fatal: bad object xxx
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `git reset --HARD commitId`?

Comment: @LuizE. It didn't work for me.

Comment: try `git gc` before execute the command

Comment: @LuizE. It doesn't seem to help

Comment: Encountered similar error today, it turns out Ubuntu dist git version 2.7.4 has this problem, after upgrade to latest git, all good.

Comment: I would like to help future readers by pointing out that if you get this error you might be in the wrong directory/repo. I was trying to get the tag or branch of a submodule commit without descending into the submodule’s subdirectory. And I was pasting the commit hash from git diff on the super repo so “It MUST exist!”

Comment: in my case i had vscode opened with WSL, GMaster opened and all 3 pointing git clients to the same repo/directory. Plus Gmaster generated a wrong Commit_ID or hash. What a mess. I will stick to using the CLI

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[**Edit 1, 19 Nov 2016**] While this would sometimes indicate repository corruption, it turns out to occur on Windows when some command—usually, another Git in another task—is holding internal files open and locked.  In this case, terminating the other task should fix it.  Original answer is below.

[**Edit 2, 6 May 2020**] Suppose `xxx` above resembles, e.g., `b34789c0b0d3b137f0bb516b417bd8d75e0cb305` (a raw hash ID).  If you got this from cut-and-paste, be sure that it's for *this* repository (it's easy to grab a hash ID from some other repository without realizing it, especially if you have multiple windows open).  If you retyped it yourself, be sure there aren't any typos.  If this involves submodules, make sure the submodule is up to date.  See the comments on the question and some of the answers, including this one.

---

`bad object` with some hexadecimal number tends to mean that a tag has an invalid reference number in it, but can also occur for a few other strange cases.  For instance, if I do a:

```
$ git tag foo
$ vi .git/refs/tags/foo
```

and change the last character (in this case from 6 to 5) and write that out:

```
$ git log foo
fatal: bad object foo
```

What exactly is the `xxx` here and where did it come from?

Comment: OK, so, it's a 40-character SHA1.  Are you sure it's a correct, valid SHA1?  Where did it come from?

Comment: I copy and pasted it from `git log`

Comment: Hm, if it's a clean paste from "git log" output, that's pretty weird then!  Can you "git show" that same ID without any errors?

Comment: OK, it sounds like the contents of that particular git object, or some object it uses (if it's a commit—which it probably is—it will refer to a "tree" object which in turn will refer to more "tree"s and "blob"s), is actually corrupt within the git repo.  I don't know of any tools for recovering whatever might be recoverable within corrupt objects.

Comment: I got the same error. As described in this question and above comments. Reason was that I have opened same project in different locations. Closing all bash and reopening solved the problem

Comment: @sajith: interesting.  I now suspect a Windows OS thing where git can't open a file if some other process is holding it open, for instance.

Comment: I got the same error when having a git-svn repo where local branches have been created from the remote ones some time ago. Trying to push these to a different remote gave this error. Once I deleted all the local branches and recreated them again from the remote ones, the error was gone and I could push to the other remote.

Comment: terminating the other task worked for me but it happened in Linux

Comment: In my case, I needed to run `git fetch` to have the remote commits in local as well.

Answer (score 37):

I don't know the exact reason why that happens. For me, it's because I forget to pull the entire repository to my local. I have 2 or more path, and each path pulls from different branch

```
/path/branch_a/ -> pulled from branch A
/path/branch_b/ -> pulled from branch B
```

on branch A, I made a few modification, and commit as usual. I want that commit (for example the commit ID is `abcdef123`) appears on branch B, so I use

```
$ cd /path/branch_b/
$ git branch
  master
  branch_a
* branch_b 

$ git cherry-pick abcdef123
```

This gives me that kind of error. So I need to pull the entire repository before getting that commit

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 257, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
remote: Total 216 (delta 187), reused 186 (delta 158)
Receiving objects: 100% (216/216), 53.13 KiB | 43 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (187/187), completed with 38 local objects.
From github.com:username/my_repo
   abcdef3..80c0d68  branch_a    -> origin/branch_a
Already up-to-date.

$ git cherry-pick abcdef123 
[branch_b ccddeef] Some commit message
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Comment: This answer reveals a common mistake using same repo in different folders with different branches. A +1 for me.

Answer (score 29):

I just ran into the same error (bad object [hash]) while attempting to merge from a branch my client didn't know about. (Similar to PrzeoR's case, but instead of needing a pull I needed to fetch)

In my case I needed to run git fetch to re-sync my client to the state of the server. Posting this here in case anyone reaches this thread the same way I did and could benefit from this insight.

```
git pull
git cherry-pick [hash]
fatal: bad object [hash]
git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 8, done. (etc.)
From github.com:repo/branch
 * [new branch] branchname

git cherry-pick [hash]
[success]
```

Comment: git fetch, remember that

Comment: Thank you. get fetch solved it. Trick is to fetch the latest commits from remote.

Answer (score 20):

In my case I was cherry-picking from another branch which I didn't pull, but I tried to copy commit's IDs from GH (I haven't got this on my local where I was cherry-picking).

Hope it helps ;-D

Comment: I was experiencing this for the same reason, but something that also added to the problem was that the commit I was attempting to cherry-pick had been squashed when being merged into the main branch, so, the original commit's SHA1 had changed. Once I figured out what the new SHA1 was that represented the same changes I was after, I was able to cherry-pick that new SHA1 just fine.

Answer (score 15):

`git fetch --all`

The git fetch command downloads commits, files, and refs from a remote repository into your local repository.

Comment: Ooops - didnt solve issue.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how i got this error,
This is the error i got.

```
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/{branchname}
fatal: failed to run repack
```

Tried pruning the git repo via `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`. It did not help.

This branch was stale and it was not important for me so i deleted the branch folder

`rm -rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/{branchname}`

ran `git gc`

It did object Enumeration and clean successfully.

Answer (score 6):

This issue can arise when there's an outdated or corrupted branch stored locally.

Deleting the file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/xxx` (after making a backup!) then fetching a fresh copy from the server worked for me.

More detail at [GitHub](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3838).

Answer (score 5):

> git pull

OR

> git fetch origin

Reason: If the commit id which you are trying to cherry pick is not available in your local git, then there is a possible of this error.

Doing a `git pull` will fix this. If this hasn't been fixed, ask the person who has shared the commit id to push the change to `origin` and do a `git pull`

Answer (score 3):

**Objects that don't exist in the repository give that error message**

E.g.:

```
 git init
 touch a
 git add a
 git commit -m 0
 # This object is not in the repository.
 git show 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

As for what causes the problem, it is hard to say without a minimal reproducible example.

Submodule woes have given me that error once.

Comment: I got it by shrinkwrapping a revision, overwriting it remotely, and then trying to install that package (it failed on `git rev-list`).

Comment: Hit upon this after finding out that a bamboo job I had to administer was using:  **Use shallow clones**
`Fetches the shallowest commit history possible. Do not use if your build depends on full repository history.`

Answer (score 3):

I got this error while trying to cherry-pick a commit whose hash I had copied from GitHub. This commit was on a branch that I hadn't pulled, just like PrzeoR.

Unlike PrzeoR a `git fetch` didn't help at first because the branch had been deleted on GitHub. 
Fortunately I was able to find the corresponding (closed) Pull Request and to restore the branch on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do git fetch to get the latest commits in sync with local

git fetch

then do

git revert

Answer (score 2):

As @jxramos [wrote in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834108/fatal-bad-object-xxx#comment114039662_40912987), this could be due to using a [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/shallow) in which case the hash you are refering might correspond to a commit which was not fetched by the shallow clone.

We got this message when migrating tests to a Gitlab CI which [by default](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone) uses a shallow clone with a depth of 20.

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67607109/why-does-git-diff-return-bad-object/73631657#73631657).

Answer (score 1):

`git rev-list --missing=<missing OID>` can also trigger a "`fatal: bad object <oid>`" error

`git rev-list --missing=print --allow-missing-tips` allows Git to handle missing objects more gracefully by printing them out instead of failing outright.
That can help identifying a missing commit.

With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e09f1254c54329773904fe25d7c545a1fb4fa920), "[`git rev-list --missing=print`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/76d1cd8e5ec07889db43c15222d5632b90f525b2/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L1005)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---missingltmissing-actiongt))</sup> has learned to optionally take `--allow-missing-tips`, which allows the objects at the starting points to be missing.

See [commit a4324ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4324babe679352a801310f8e30f3cbcd9c1f16b) (28 Feb 2024), and [commit 7b644c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b644c8c5a67cdda4a15ac91976eb29f5e29b796), [commit 686101f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/686101ffc949acc4e840037145a97f647aa9f48c), [commit eaf07b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eaf07b7d15e067305d33150eb98bf0351f9f4cbd), [commit 3ff56af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ff56af99b1c9becd9e603b59986359f553e62a8) (14 Feb 2024) by [Christian Couder (`chriscool`)](https://github.com/chriscool).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 76d1cd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76d1cd8e5ec07889db43c15222d5632b90f525b2), 07 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b644c8c5a67cdda4a15ac91976eb29f5e29b796): allow missing tips with --missing=[print|allow*]
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Linus Arver</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Couder</sup>

> In [9830926](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9830926c7db626e374b887eeecb96515e2956638) ("`rev-list`: add commit object support in `--missing` option", 2023-10-27, Git v2.43.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57e216d03d3f6630771530f9c3feb0aa7f8aaad4)) we fixed the `--missing` option in [`git rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7b644c8c5a67cdda4a15ac91976eb29f5e29b796/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup> so that it works with with missing commits, not just blobs/trees.
>
> Unfortunately, such a command would still fail with a "fatal: bad object " if it is passed a missing commit, blob or tree as an argument (before the rev walking even begins).
>
> When such a command is used to find the dependencies of some objects, for example the dependencies of quarantined objects (see the ["QUARANTINE ENVIRONMENT" section in the `git-receive-pack(1)` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack#_quarantine_environment)), it would be better if the command would instead consider such missing objects, especially commits, in the same way as other missing objects.
>
> If, for example `--missing=print` is used, it would be nice for some use cases if the missing tips passed as arguments were reported in the same way as other missing objects instead of the command just failing.
>
> We could introduce a new option to make it work like this, but most users are likely to prefer the command to have this behavior as the default one.
> Introducing a new option would require another dumb loop to look for that option early, which isn't nice.

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7b644c8c5a67cdda4a15ac91976eb29f5e29b796/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L1022-L1025):

> If some tips passed to the traversal are missing, they will be
> considered as missing too, and the traversal will ignore them. In case
> we cannot get their Object ID though, an error will be raised.

> ### [`revision`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4324babe679352a801310f8e30f3cbcd9c1f16b): fix --missing=[print|allow*] for annotated tags
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Couder</sup>
>
> That fix still doesn't work when an argument passed to the command is an annotated tag pointing to a missing commit though.
> In that case [`git rev-list --missing=...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a4324babe679352a801310f8e30f3cbcd9c1f16b/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L1005)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---missingltmissing-actiongt))</sup> still errors out with a "`fatal: bad object <oid>`" error where `<oid>` is the object ID of the missing commit.
>
> Let's fix this issue, and also, while at it, let's add tests not just for annotated tags but also for regular tags and branches.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error when trying to cherry-pick (on A) the commit of another branch ( B).
Issue was stupid, simply forgot to git push the commit (B).

Answer (score 0):

The reason I ran into it was simple. I was switching back and forth between the main repository and a submodule. I tried to do a diff between one hash (in the main repository) and another that I copied from SourceTree, thinking it was an easy to get the old HEAD (I had regressed one revision to track down a regression). The old HEAD hash I grabbed was that of a submodule, and `git diff` was put out with me for feeding it garbage. That's how I ended up here, and that's when I realized it was operator error. If your hash is from a different repository git will scold you with this message. However, if you do feed it garbage, would it not be better to report "XXX not a revision in this repository"? It is every bit as general an error message as "bad object" and quite a bit less likely to send someone to stack overflow for answers. I wonder if the folks in the git community would accept that pull request...

Comment: if you are very lucky(?) then both repos have a have the same hash - but not at all ever referencing the same object or state.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue, finally had to remove bad object sha entry from `pack-refs` file

**Location :** ./git/pack-refs

Answer (score 0):

in my case this was caused by `git filter-repo` which by default replaces commit hashes in commit messages. then parsing hashes from these patched messages gives the error `fatal: bad object xxx`. fix: `git filter-repo --preserve-commit-hashes`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have the stupidest of reasons, which is being on the wrong repo. So, probably double check that as well...