# Shelljs exec failed on git cherry-pick

Tags: node.js, git, shelljs

I have a script that cherry-picks a commit using `shelljs`.

Here is my LOC that does cherry-picking using `shelljs`.

```
shell.exec('git cherry-pick commitid -X theirs');
Note: commitid = sha of commit I want to cherry-pick.
```

shelljs is throwing the following error:

```
fatal: bad object: commitid
```

e.g

```
fatal: bad object: 7854484884 (commitid)
```

Comment: On the presumption that your git repo status is OK, are you certain that the commit id exists somewhere in the repo? That error regularly comes from when the commit itself is not present in the git history.

Comment: Yes repo is clean and the commit exists.

Comment: Do any of these items help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834108/fatal-bad-object-xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue.

My project structure looks like this:

```
project1 (git repo)
  cherrypick.js
  project2 (another git repo)
```

I wanted to cherry-pick a commit in project2 and merge it in different branch.

But the code written was in project1. Hence I had to add this line and it works.

```
shell.exec('cd project2');
shell.exec('git cherry-pick commitid -X theirs');
```