# Why does git diff return 'bad object'?

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am running a ci task on my Gitlab server. One of the actions is to call an exe on the build runner machine which does some updates.

I pass through the SHA1s from `$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` and `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` and the code calls:

```
git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

Usually it gives me a list of file names which have changed in the commit but sometimes I get the error:

```
fatal: bad object abcd1234
                  ^
                  |-- This is the $CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

The repo has just been downloaded to the build runner so it is up to date, why would the git diff return a bad object here?

Comment: What runner are you using? Do you need to research difference between powershell and Linux shell?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20264177/3216427, that message means the repository is corrupt. Do you get other strange file system issues in that setup? Do you see any other error messages from previous Git commands in the CI recipe?

Comment: I'm not sure the solutions there would be of any help, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/60971746/3216427 says doing an extra `git fetch origin` helped them. It's all a bit mysterious to me how a Git sandbox gets corrupted in the first place, unless something is unstable in the environment.

Comment: To clarify, does the error actually output `fatal: bad object $CI_COMMIT_SHA` with the variable not replaced or is the variable replaced?

Comment: @KamilCuk, the problem is that is usually works.  The runner is no different between runs that work and ones which do not

Comment: @joanis, no - everything else is fine.

Comment: @joanis, I tried the git fetch and then git diff and it worked  when I did it by hand but did not seem to fix the issue when used in the runner

Comment: @GaëlJ, it is with the variable replaced with the actual value

Comment: Can you add `git fsck` to your build recipe, and see if the output provides any clues?

Answer (score 5):

If the commit is "old" it could be missing from the clone because Gitlab uses a [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/shallow) with a depth of 20 [by default](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone).

This is why you see this message in the job's log:

> Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...

Possible solutions:

- use the [web interface](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone) to increase this value for your project (or disable shallow cloning).
- [override](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/large_repositories/index.html#shallow-cloning) variable `GIT_DEPTH` from `.gitlab-ci.yml`
- re-clone the repo manually using a standard clone inside its `.gitlab-ci.yml` scripts
- stop relying on "old" hashes

Comment: The note about 'shallow clone' was key to helping me solve a similar problem with Azure DevOps pipelines using `git diff-tree...`. After I disabled shallow clone in the pipeline definition, then the git statement would work. Snippet of YAML `- checkout: self
  clean: true
  fetchDepth: 0`.

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch origin $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME                               git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA`

It helped me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).